# Centralizer of unique cyclic subgroup of order equal to exponent of group 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I rewrite my question in a better way.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K\leq G$ the unique cyclic subgroup of $G$ with $|K|=exp(G)$, where $exp(G)=lcm\{|g|\big|g\in G\}$. Is $K=C_{G}(K)$?

Comment: Such a cyclic subgroup need not exist; for example $G=S_3$.

Comment: Hint: If $C_G(K)$ is bigger than $K$, then $G$ has an abelian subgroup $A$ properly containing $K$. What alternatives will the structure theory of finite abelian groups leave for $A$? Can you show that it will have more than one subgroup isomorphic to $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the existence and uniqueness of a cyclic subgroup $K=\langle k\rangle$ for which $|K|=\exp G$. Note that such a subgroup need not exist or be unique in general.

Hint: if $g\in C_G(K)\setminus K$ consider $\langle gk\rangle$.